# How do I set the umask for files and directories created from the GUI in MacOS X Lion (10.7)?

Tags: osx-lion, file-permissions

I've set my umask in my .bashrc file to 007. Any files created on the command line after loading my bashrc file respects this setting. I want to be able to set the umask to 007 for any files created using non-command line apps.

This document talks about [setting the umask via launchd.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2202) And it kind of works. If I follow these directions I can change the default permissions on a GUI created file from `rw-r--r--` to `rw-rw----` but the directories still are not group writeable (i.e. I want them to be `rwxrwx---` but they are `rwxr-x---` instead)

The analog on Linux would be `/etc/login.defs` as the place to set the umask.

What do I change in order for the umask to be set properly (i.e. the way I want it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for the best answer so far: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42421/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-permissions-for-gui-apps-in-lion/

No real solution though (yet).